# IndexPutTemplate is deprecated: Legacy index templates are deprecated in favor of composable templates

Tags: go, elasticsearch

just today I got this error on linter on legacy codebase:

```golang
app/providers/elasticAdapter/provider.go:81:9: SA1019: p.client.IndexPutTemplate is deprecated: Legacy index templates are deprecated in favor of composable templates. (staticcheck)
        svc := p.client.IndexPutTemplate("ignore_corrupted")
               ^
app/providers/elasticAdapter/provider.go:82:12: SA1019: svc.BodyJson(map[string]interface{}{
        "index_patterns": []string{"*"},
        "settings": map[string]interface{}{
                "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true,
        },
}).Do is deprecated: Legacy index templates are deprecated in favor of composable templates. (staticcheck)
        _, err := svc.BodyJson(map[string]interface{}{
                  ^
```

The message not really clear

```
// IndexPutTemplate creates or updates an index template (v1/legacy version before 7.8).
//
// This service implements the legacy version of index templates as described
// in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/indices-templates-v1.html.
//
// See e.g. IndexPutIndexTemplate and IndexPutComponentTemplate for the new version(s).
//
// Deprecated: Legacy index templates are deprecated in favor of composable templates.
```

what I should do? If I use IndexPutIndexTemplate, it seems doesn't have `template:{settings:{index.mapping.ignore_malformed:true}}` property in the documentation

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @Briomkez i ignored the lint, we're in the middle of moving out from elasticsearch anyway